# How to display data from multiple columns in Mapbox?

Tags: popup, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I make a map for a mapbox, the data goes through the geoserver and gets to the map. Problems arose with the fact that in the pop-up window I need to display data from several columns, but so far it turns out only from one, how to make from several at the same time?

```
map.on('click', 'Piemonte', function (e) {
  new mapboxgl.Popup()
  .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
  .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.Region)
  .addTo(map);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The `setHTML` method takes an HTML string.  So, you can show anything you need with HTML/CSS

You can loop through the features and build the HTML

```
var popupHtml = '<table><th><td>Col1</td></th>'
for (var i = 0; i < e.features.length; i++) {
  popupHtml += '<tr><td>' + e.features[i].properties.Region + '</td></tr>'
}
popupHtml += '</table>'
```